# Get tweet url or tweet id using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

So as the question suggests I'm trying to figure out how to get either the tweet id # or the whole url. Using the code below I can get the tweet(s) i want and print them out. However instead of printing them I want to get either the url or at least the tweet id (so that I can make my own url) that I can use in my code later down the line. Any advice? not seeing anything in the tweepy docs about this but perhaps there is something i'm missing or something else I can use to achieve this?

```
import tweepy

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("*******", "*****")
auth.set_access_token("******", "*****")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Function to extract tweets 
def get_tweets(username): 

        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username,count = 1) 

        tmp=[]

        tweets_for_csv = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
        for t in tweets_for_csv:
            tmp.append(t)
        print(tmp)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_tweets("@username")
```

This code works fine just trying to learn what I would add to get the desired data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the Tweet ID, you can get to the final URL like this:

Append it to `https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/` (+ the id)

Follow the HTTP redirect.

It sounds like you're not able to get the ID itself - that will be in the `tweet.id` value for each Tweet - currently you're just saving `tweet.text`

Comment: Sorry I suppose I didn't explain right or I'm not understanding what you mean. My intent is to get the tweet.id. Are you saying it is impossible or that I am not doing that currently with my code. I'm aware that my code isn't allowing me to I just have this currently to test that I can infact get the tweet, but it sounds like this method only gathers the text and data isn't even involved with this code.

Comment: The call to the API brings back a single Tweet  (`count = 1`) containing all of the data, including the text, ID, timestampt etc. The code goes on to just save the text into the `tmp` variable. Try saving `tweet.id` instead of `tweet.text`

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I see what you mean with your first comment now.