# Extracting Tweet links which contains specific keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, tweets

Is it possible to get fist 100 tweet link when we search for a particular key word? Currently I have this code which fetches tweet data

```
keyword = raw_input("Please input the CVE which you want to pull data for")
#Fetching tweets 
tweets = api.search(keyword, count=1, lang='en', exclude='retweets', tweet_mode='extended')
for tweet in tweets:
print (tweet)
```

but I am looking for something like this. When I try searching CVE-2020-1472
I should be presented with following

```
https://twitter.com/_r_netsec/status/1305102204278198273 
https://twitter.com/_r_netsec/status/1305491014849720320 
https://twitter.com/djrevmoon/status/1305446256525930496 
https://twitter.com/dragosr/status/1307204066255073281 
and so on ….
```

All the tweet links which has text “**CVE-2020-1472**” in it

Comment: Maybe this answer solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918965/get-tweet-url-or-tweet-id-using-tweepy

Comment: @pastaleg this one looks promising bro. I am currently in the process of testing it. Thanks for the quick reply. I will update this thread once the desired result is achieved